# Change VS2012 Color Theme programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vs-extensibility

I'm looking for a resource or example code on how to change the color theme in VS2012.

I'd like to do this dependant on the value of an AppSetting entry in the app.config.

Ideally when when the app isn't running and the theme would change once the file is edited.

However, I'd appreciate anything towards that goal.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you can use free Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor, which you can download here:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05

This will add “Theme” menu in your VS.
Also you can change your icons: here http://vsip.codeplex.com/ you can download Visual Studio Icon Patcher (But VS2010 should be also installed for this to work).

But, if you want to implement your own code to change themes, the best way is making own extensions which look like VSPackage. You can read recommendations how to do this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb165437.aspx

And in other articles at this site you can find more information about implementing your own ideas in the VS.